# Blocking calls on Akka HTTP server

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

## Why is my akka-http server dropping connections?

The following is a simplified version of a problem I am facing.

I have a akka-http server.
On a route, I have to make a blocking call to a remote service. I **cannot** change to a non-blocking client:

```
val routes: Route = post { 
  complete {
      myBlockingService.makeRequest()                   
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate the above is not appropriate as it is vulnerable to thread starvation, whereby the threads of the default dispatcher, which are responsible for all the "piping" in the system, would become blocked handling my *blocking* request, grinding the entire system to a halt.

Short of swapping for a non-blocking client, it is my understanding there are two approaches to deal with this. 1) Using a `blocking` *block*, or 2) Use a separate, specific thread-pool for the blocking requests.

## Approach 1

```
import scala.concurrent.blocking
val routes: Route = get { 
  complete {
    blocking {
      myBlockingService.makeRequest()                   
    }
  }
}
```

My question really only concerns `Approach 2` below, but for completeness, I will describe my understanding here as well.
The blocking *block* will hint the thread pool of the default dispatcher (fork-join-pool)
that the call is blocking, which enables the pool to potentially increase the number of threads, and avoid starvation. It is my understanding that there is a maximum number of **extra** threads that java's fork-join-pool is willing to create for blocking calls, and that this number cannot be changed by me.
By profiling the system, I indeed see a spike in the number of threads spawned during moments in which the external blocking service becomes slow. I saw up to 1000 threads.
This approach improved the system to some extent.

## Approach 2

```
// implicit val defaultDispatcher = system.dispatcher // I am not doing this!!
implicit val customThreadPool: ExecutionContext = <a-custom-thread-pool-backed-by-UN-bounded-queue>

val routes: Route = get { 
  complete {
    Future {
      myBlockingService.makeRequest()                   
    }
  }
}
```

I was mainly hopeful on approach 2. Sadly, it worked only to some extent.
The crux of this post, is that I don't understand why this doesn't work completely.

When the `myBlockingService.makeRequest()` becomes temporarily slow and the incoming requests reach the low hundreds per second, the akka server starts dropping requests (TCP connections). This happens regardless of the size of the custom thread-pool I pass in. I have tried from 10 threads to hundreds. I have also tried with more than 1 kind of thread-pool.

I would have expected the system to either endure the temporary slowness, **OR** to fail with a memory overflow due to too many elements on the unbounded queue backing the custom thread-pool/execution-context.

After all, the queue is unbounded! So why doesn't the akka dispatcher threads, which are responsible for handling the incoming requests, don't just consume the requests from the TCP layer and pile them up on that execution-context? I do not understand why the akka-system drops requests instead.

Further insights:

- By profiling the app, I can see my custom thread pool handling the requests just fine. During those moments of relative slowness, the threads are governed by `WAITING/PARKING` states, concerning the blocking IO call, which can last up to a few seconds. This is inline to what I expected.
- During the whole time (i.e. normal and relative slowness moments), the fork-join-pool backing the akka system maintains 32 threads, which is consistent with the configuration (`.conf` file) I have.
- Because I control the custom thread pool, I can see that the default dispatcher threads (i.e. the `foo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1` threads) are the ones inserting elements. This is in line with my understanding. The akka system handles the incoming request, and the logic of the route is such that it submits the task to my execution-context.
- On the profiling of the akka dispatcher threads, I spot nothing obviously different between the times when the system is running smoothly and the times the remote service slows down and akka starts dropping requests.

Just to drive the point home, the behaviour I expected is:
If the blocking calls start taking to long, and there is a fixed number of threads on the custom execution-context to deal with those, then I expected akka to **still** accept incoming requests and insert new tasks onto the custom execution-context/queue. These tasks could potentially take a long time and the upstream client would experience a long wait, maybe even a timeout on their side, but eventually the system would catch up. Instead akka just drops the connections. Any insights as to what the explanation might be?

This question might be related:
What does akka-http do with the futures on a `complete {Future {<something>}}` route? Does it poll it?

Edit:
[image: Adding CPU usage for approach 2]

Comment: What is the CPU usage when the server is running slow? If you are creating 1000 threads that alone is going to be a significant burden. And if approach 2 generates fewer threads then that implies it is less efficient than approach 1 (which is the one I would go with)

Comment: thanks Tim. I have added the CPU usage to the post.

Comment: What is the actual failure mode? Are connections rejected or accepted and then dropped later with an error?

Comment: Thank you. The client received mostly the errors a) `java.net.UnknownHostException`, and b) `io.netty.channel.ChannelException`, when the "slowness moments" begin. Also, these errors are associated with requests that never reach the Route. I can see this as I am logging all the requests that reach it. Therefore my suspicion is that the akka default dispatcher is not consuming the requests fast enough from the TCP layer, and these 2 errors are associated with that. Don't have further details on the connections atm.